# Fixed: Angular Http request error json parse

Tags: php, angular, request

I need help understand the problem here.
I have a project using API PHP that return an array in JSON format, on local host works great the products are seen fine, but when i send to my online server the produtcs does't show.

The request it's made by angular.
and get the satus code 200 ok, but the **error.**

```
angular.min.js:107 SyntaxError: Unexpected token [ in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at uc (angular.min.js:15)
    at $b (angular.min.js:82)
    at angular.min.js:83
    at n (angular.min.js:7)
    at cd (angular.min.js:83)
    at c (angular.min.js:84)
    at angular.min.js:119
    at r.$eval (angular.min.js:133)
    at r.$digest (angular.min.js:130)
```

**the response on online returns;**

```
0[{"id":1,"nome":"bola berlimddd","descricao":"recheada creme de ovo","quantidade":5,"preco":1,"imagem":"bola berlim.jpg","data":"2017-03-13"},{"id":2,"nome":"lanche","descricao":"lanche misto","quantidade":10,"preco":1,"imagem":"lanche.jpg","data":"2017-03-13"},{"id":3,"nome":"bolos variados","descricao":"com creme","quantidade":20,"preco":1.5,"imagem":"sopa.jpg","data":"2017-03-13"},{"id":5,"nome":"bolos variados","descricao":"com creme","quantidade":20,"preco":1.5,"imagem":"sopa.jpg","data":"2017-03-13"},{"id":6,"nome":"croissant","descricao":"com queijo\/ fiambre \/ misto","quantidade":20,"preco":1.5,"imagem":"sopa.jpg","data":"2017-03-13"},{"id":7,"nome":"especialidades","descricao":"com chantily","quantidade":20,"preco":1.5,"imagem":"sopa.jpg","data":"2017-03-13"}]
```

**the response on local host returns;**

```
[{"id":1,"nome":"bola berlimddd","descricao":"recheada creme de ovo","quantidade":5,"preco":1,"imagem":"bola berlim.jpg","data":"2017-03-13"},{"id":2,"nome":"lanche","descricao":"lanche misto","quantidade":10,"preco":1,"imagem":"lanche.jpg","data":"2017-03-13"},{"id":3,"nome":"bolos variados","descricao":"com creme","quantidade":20,"preco":1.5,"imagem":"sopa.jpg","data":"2017-03-13"},{"id":5,"nome":"bolos variados","descricao":"com creme","quantidade":20,"preco":1.5,"imagem":"sopa.jpg","data":"2017-03-13"},{"id":6,"nome":"croissant","descricao":"com queijo\/ fiambre \/ misto","quantidade":20,"preco":1.5,"imagem":"sopa.jpg","data":"2017-03-13"},{"id":7,"nome":"especialidades","descricao":"com chantily","quantidade":20,"preco":1.5,"imagem":"sopa.jpg","data":"2017-03-13"}]
```

**Has u can see i think the problem it's the 0 first, and i don't now how to remove it.**

Comment: This problem doesn't seem to be anything to do with Angular; give a [mcve] of the API.

Comment: What your server returns is probably just not valid JSON. If what you get from the server starts with `0[{"id":1,"`, then the error is expected. The `0` at the beginning makes it invalid.

Comment: Hello.The problem was on my online server, the version of PHP it's diferent from my local server. E change to same version, PHP7 and every thing works again. Tks .